# I have solved how to display the top three scores but not the respective names of the top three players

Tags: android

This is the jave file to show the three highest scores but I do not know what the code is if I want to display the names of the three highest scorers.Do I write the same conditional structures for the high scorers using three new strings? I don´t want to use Google Leaderboard and I would like to follow the same structure I used for high scores.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


public class recordofscores extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_logout;
    private TextView tvEmail, yourscore, highestscore;
    private Session session;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES="MyPrefs";
    public static final String Name="nameKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String savedname = "scorerOne";
    String name;

    int lastScore;
    int best1,best2, best3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_recordofscores);


        sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences (MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        yourscore=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.yourscore);
        highestscore=(TextView) findViewById (R.id.highestscore);

        tvEmail = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvEmail);

        tvEmail.setText (sharedpreferences.getString (Name, "n") + " is logged in");
        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences ("PREFS", 0);
        lastScore=preferences.getInt ("lastScore", 0);
        best1=preferences.getInt ("best1", 0);
        best2=preferences.getInt ("best2", 0);
        best3=preferences.getInt ("best3", 0);

        if (lastScore > best3) {
            best3=lastScore;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit ( );
            editor.putInt ("best3", best3);
            editor.apply ( );
        }
        if (lastScore > best2) {
            int temp=best2;
            best2=lastScore;
            best3=temp;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit ( );
            editor.putInt ("best3", best3);
            editor.putInt ("best2", best2);
            editor.apply ( );
        }
        if (lastScore > best1) {
            int temp=best1;
            best1=lastScore;
            best2=temp;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit ( );
            editor.putInt ("best2", best2);
            editor.putInt ("best1", best1);
            editor.apply ( );
        }



        yourscore.setText (sharedpreferences.getString (Name, "n") + " - " + lastScore);
highestscore.setText("1 - " + best1 +" \n" +
                     "2 - " + best2 + "\n" +
                      "3 - " + best3 );





        session = new Session(this);
        if(!session.loggedin()){
            logout();
        }
        btn_logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void logout(){
        session.setLoggedin(false);
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(recordofscores.this,LoginActivity.class));
    }
}`
```

Comment: dont use shared pref for this. you need some sort of DB to store this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can save three `String`s in your `sharedpreferences` **OR** save data in a local database using `Room`. `Room` will provide you an easy way to save a table instead of a single object, so if you'll want to save more parameters or more scores (say last 100 scores) it would be easy. [Room Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hadas - if I make three new strings, would they be as follows -get preferences -  topscorer1=preferences.getString("topscorer1",null) and would the save to shared preferences be - putString("topscorer1",topscorer1)?

Comment: Yes.. but I recommend using `Room`. If you want to know more about preferences here is a link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences